# Why does \psplot need higher plotpoints when plotting a function on the left of the function's asymptote?

Tags: pstricks

The following animation shows the behavior intuitively. `\psplot` seems to work in an asymmetric way. It can plot the right part with the default `plotpoints` but it is not the case when it plots the left part. We need to increase the `plotpoints` to obtain the complete graph on the left part.

[image]

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-plot}

\pstVerb{/myDiv {dup 0 eq {pop 0 lt {-1e30} {1e30} ifelse} {div} ifelse} def}

\def\f#1{1 #1 myDiv}
\def\g#1{\f{#1 neg}}


\psset{yMinValue=-4,yMaxValue=4}

\begin{document}
\multido{\i=7+12}{20}{%
\psset{plotpoints=\i}
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid=bottom](-2,-4)(2,4)
\psclip{\psframe[linestyle=none,dimen=middle](-2,-4)(2,4)}
    \psplot[linecolor=red]{-2}{2}{\f{x}}
    \psplot[linecolor=blue]{-2}{2}{\g{x}}
    \rput(0,0){\textcolor{red}{plotpoints: \i}}
\endpsclip
\end{pspicture}}
\end{document}
```

Why does `\psplot` need higher `plotpoints` when plotting a function on the left of the function's asymptote? Is it a bug?

Comment: you are plotting _one_ function with a vertical asymptote in it. on the left the last line segment is plotted to (x|y<MaxValue) on the right the _first_ line is plotted from (x|y>MaxValue) to (x|y<MaxValue). That is different to the plotstyle dots where you get a symmetrical behaviour.

Comment: @Herbert: Is it a good idea to add an option to  `\psplot` to specify the asymptote `x=a` such that the `\psplot` can choose the correct starting points for both sides around the asymptote line?

Comment: in general yes, but at the moment too much work ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

for an even number of plotpoints the x values are *not* symmetrical to the y axis, the reason why you didn't reach the not allowed division by zero 1/0 but have not the same distance of the points from the y axis. Choosing an odd number of plotpoints, eg 13, creates symmetrical x values but also has x=0 in the set. However, 1/0 can be catched by an own division operator and `plotpoints=6*n+1` with n=1,2,... will give a symmetrical behaviour for this kind of function.

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-plot}

\begin{document}
\pstVerb{ % control the division, y x is on the stack
  /myDiv { dup 0 eq { pop 0 lt { -1e30 }
                               {  1e30 } ifelse } 
       { div } ifelse } def
}

\psset{plotpoints=24,plotstyle=dots}
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid=bottom](-2,-5)(4,5)
    \psplot[linecolor=red]{-2}{4}{1 x myDiv}
    \psplot[linecolor=blue]{-2}{4}{-1 x myDiv}
\end{pspicture}

\psset{plotpoints=25,plotstyle=dots}
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid=bottom](-2,-5)(4,5)
    \psplot[linecolor=red]{-2}{4}{1 x myDiv}
    \psplot[linecolor=blue]{-2}{4}{-1 x myDiv}
\end{pspicture}

\psset{plotpoints=241,plotstyle=line,yMaxValue=5}
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid=bottom](-2,-5)(4,5)
    \psplot[linecolor=red]{-2}{4}{1 x myDiv}
    \psplot[linecolor=blue]{-2}{4}{-1 x myDiv}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Is `1e30` the maximum value allowed in PS?

Comment: that is the value accepted by all PS levels

Comment: If we gradually increase `plotpoints`  for the last `pspicture` with `plotstyle=line`, the graph is actually still asymmetric for the first several `plotpoints` and it reaches the steady state later.

Comment: sure, only the `|y| < yMaxValue` are plotted, there is no interpolation

Comment: I still don't understand why `plotstyle=dots` always produces a symmetric result but `plotstyle=line` does not. In my mental model,   `plotstyle=line` should be symmetric as well if it uses the same dots as `plotstyle=dots` does.

Comment: dots and lines are not the same. We have a sequence of x|y values which creates a _path_ when using plotstyle line